# Bookmarks not visible in Delicious

Tags: bookmarks, delicious

I saved some bookmarks with proper tags, but these are displayed only when I log in. These are not available in the recent list on the homepage without logging in even though I searched with tag or URL.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you mark those bookmarks as private?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Delicious was retired in 2017. Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_(website)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your bookmarks are just private. You can see it if they have a lock icon.
To fix it, you can select all of them, click "bulk edit" and make them public.